# Redux devtools statePersist refreshing

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, redux, redux-devtools

When I want to use the statePresist tool (the debug session) I put a query string at the end like this:
http://localhost:3000/#/?debug_session=tal

and if I play with the state, and then refresh, I lose my query string (?debug_session=tal is gone).

so I'm in a blank state.

is there a way to refresh and keep the state? 
(And I also would like to achive that i will work with routing - Like im in my index screen with debug session, and then I move to ./articles , and even when I'm not in my index I would still get the same session).

thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Redux DevTools Extension already includes [the `persistState` enhancer](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/blob/master/src/persistState.js) and there's not much you can do here except adding `debug_session=tal` from your code when changing the location.

In order to solve this and other issues with localStorage quota and unserializable data, I made [a PR](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/pull/276), so you'll be able to get the state persisted right from the extension without using localStorage and adding anything to the url.